Flask and Dash Integration
I have two applications working together (Flask and Dash). The Flask application receives and processes data, calls the function that creates the Dash application, and sends a request with the id_session used to access the correct user data. The Dash application receives the request and updates the Dash layout. This integration works correctly in a localhost environment, but on PythonAnywhere, I am having issues with the correct updating of the graphs in the Dash layout. From what I can identify, it seems that the update signal reception in the callback is not working correctly. The request is received, and the data is accessed correctly within the “update-signal” function, but the callback does not respond correctly every time. Sometimes the graphs are updated with incorrect data.
FLASK CODE
flask_app = Flask(__name__)
flask_app.secret_key = 'supersecretkey'

import dash_app
dash_app.create_dash_app(flask_app)

@flask_app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        session_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        session['session_id'] = session_id

        upload_folder = os.path.join('uploads', session_id)
        os.makedirs(upload_folder, exist_ok=True)
        database_file = request.files['database_file']
        data = pd.read_csv(database_file)

    # Data Manipulation Code

        data_path = os.path.join(upload_folder, 'temp_data.csv')
        data.to_csv(data_path, index=False)

        requests.post('http://my_domain/update-data', data={'session_id': session_id})

        return redirect("http://my_domain/dashapp/")

    return render_template('index.html')

DASH CODE
def create_dash_app(flask_app):

    FONT_AWESOME = ["https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css"]
    dash_app = Dash(server=flask_app, url_base_pathname='/dashapp/', external_stylesheets=FONT_AWESOME)
    server = dash_app.server

    dash_app.layout = dbc.Container(children=[
        dcc.Store(id='data-update-signal', data=0),

         ... Rest of the Layout Code...

    ])
 
    global data
    data = pd.DataFrame({})

    @server.route('/update-data', methods=['POST'])
    def update_data():
        session_id = request.form.get('session_id')
        if not session_id:
            return "Session ID missing", 400

        download_folder = os.path.join('uploads', session_id)

        global data
        data_path = os.path.join(download_folder, 'temp_data.csv')
        data = pd.read_csv(data_path)

        current_signal = dash_app.layout.children[0].data
        new_signal = current_signal + 1
        dash_app.layout.children[0].data = new_signal

        return "Data updated", 200

    @dash_app.callback(
        Output('graph1', 'figure'),
        Output('graph3', 'figure'),
        Output('graph4', 'figure'),
        Input(ThemeSwitchAIO.ids.switch("theme"), "value"),
        [Input('data-update-signal', 'data')]
    )
    def card1(toggle, data_update_signal):
        template_theme1 = "flatly"
        template_theme2 = "darkly"

        template = template_theme1 if toggle else template_theme2

        fig1 = go.Figure()
        ... Rest of the Fig Code ...

        fig3 = go.Figure()
    ... Rest of the Fig Code ...

        fig4 = go.Figure()
    ... Rest of the Fig Code ...

        return fig1, fig3, fig4

    return dash_app

Resolving the issue with graph updates

I would suggest adding some logging to your code (prints to stderr will appear in your error log) so you can work out what is different when you get graphs with incorrect data
